# Disable workflow activation function in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

In Dynamics CRM 2011 I want to disable workflow activation for some users. These users still can create, update and deactivate workflows, but only specific user "workflow publisher" can activate workflows. How can I do this?
I was thinking about creating security role and check this role using plugin when user try to activate workflow, but I can not register plugin on workflow (process) entity.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This is not really an answer but I'll just let you know that this is not possible - not without figuring out some major unsupported modifications to the database. None of the messages for workflow entity are available for custom plugins. Wish I could be of more help. I think you would have issues when the owner of the workflow is not the one trying to activate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply assign all workflows to yourself, and remove these users' ability to reassign workflows, then you have effectively taken away activate privileges.  There is no security role regarding activating processes, but there is security around assigning workflows, so don't allow users to reassign these workflows once you own them.  I wouldn't recommend giving create capabilities if you are going to be the process gatekeeper either, since they would be able to create their own then activate them.